# how to call async function in .on event nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I am reading a CSV file using csv-parser npm module createReadStream.

```
export default async function main() {
  const readstream = fs.createReadStream('src/working_file.csv');
stream.on('data', data => {
const val = await fun(param1, param2, param3);
   });
  fun(param1, param2, param3){
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have to call function fun with await but it is throwing me the error.*await is only valid in async function*. Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Just indicate that the callback function is `async`.

```
stream.on('data', async data => {
  // Do async stuff
})
```

Comment: each data has a JSON object and I have written a function call in call back function. Which is calling by all the objects at once. Can you tell me why? and I want to call the function in callback function one after once.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you await must return a ***promise***.

```
export default async function main() {
  const readstream = fs.createReadStream('src/working_file.csv');
stream.on('data', async data => {
   try{
      const val = await fun(param1, param2, param3);
    } catch(err) {
    //handle error
    }

   });
  fun(param1, param2, param3){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         resolve(some_value)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: It needs to be specified as `async` and that very change means it _does_ return a promise, by definition. An expression that is awaited is wrapped in a promise meaning that anything may be awaited

Comment: I've tried this and it did not work for me. See this link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308963/how-to-stream-read-an-s3-json-file-to-postgresql-using-async-await-in-a-nodejs-1